# How to get property value in js object when key is unknown

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
a = [
     {81.25: {p:81.25}}, 
     {81.26: {p:81.26}}
    ]
```

I want to loop through array ang get value of **p** in each element:

```
for (var key in a) {
   console.log(a[key]); // outputs {81.25: Object}
   //How do i get p value out of the current element?
}
```

EDIT: sorry for misleading, I wodnt want to loop againg - thought may be some way to get **first object inside current one** and to get it's property p.

Comment: use `console.log(a[key].p);`

Comment: @zzzzBov: *when key is unknown* would suggest the OP doesn't know the property is always `p`.

Comment: a[key].p is undefined

Comment: @MattBurland, OP *does* say that he wants to "get value of **p** in each element", which tells me that he knows the key is `p`, but I did misread it in that `a` is an array, so it'd be `a[i][key].p` with a doubly-nested `for` loop.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Read the title. It's pretty obvious *in context* that `p` is just a placeholder for the unknown property.

Comment: @MattBurland, to me the unknown property appears to be `81.25` and `81.26`, but that's a matter of interpretation. I wouldn't say it's obvious at all.

Comment: If you don't want to loop over the properties of an object, and you know you only want the *first* property, you might think of using `Object.keys()`, however, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), it will return keys in the same order as `for...in` which is to say, it's not guaranteed that the keys will be in any particular order. I don't think you can ever count on the order of properties of an object because the order of properties really doesn't have any special meaning. If you care about order, use an array.

Comment: Of course, if you know your objects *only* have one property, then order isn't an issue. But you still might want to rethink how you are doing this at a higher level anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer.

```
for (var key in a) {
 console.log(a[key][Object.keys(a[key])[0]].p); // 81.25
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a standard `for` loop for the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (typeof a[i] == object) { //object test
        for (var key in a[i]) {
            if (a[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(a[i][key]); //here ya go
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between my and standard loop? strandard takes more coding and works the same...

Comment: @ProstoTrader: a) it's barely more code. b) `for...in` is not guaranteed to iterate the indexes of an array *in order* and will include other properties that an array might have other than just the items in the array. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Short version: use regular `for` loops for arrays and `for...in` (with a `hasOwnProperty` check) for objects.

Comment: if you have one loop it doesn't matter, I agree.
But if you have hundreeds of those loops, trust me - writing "for (a in b)" is much much simplier thend writing "for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)".

Comment: @MattBurland, thanks for clarifying the difference. Now I know for sure there's not that much difference )

Answer (score 1):

Parse this way,

```
a[0]["81.25"].p
a[1]["81.26"].p
```

if you using loop

```
for (var key in a) {
  for (var key1 in a[key]) {
        if (typeof a[key][key1] == "object") {
            console.log(a[key][key1]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No var key in a for a normal array

Comment: Think you've mixed up your indexes there.