# Parsing JSON with jQuery- Root node is timestamped

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am using a service that returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "Airport Terminal A Departures: October 6, 2014, 8:31 pm": [
        {
            "Northbound": [
                {
                    "direction": "N",
                    "path": "R4N",
                    "train_id": "462",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Warminster",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 08:43:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 08:43:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "N",
                    "path": "R4N",
                    "train_id": "9464",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Temple U",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 09:13:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 09:13:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "N",
                    "path": "R4N",
                    "train_id": "466",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Warminster",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 09:43:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 09:43:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "N",
                    "path": "R4N",
                    "train_id": "9468",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Temple U",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 10:13:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 10:13:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "N",
                    "path": "R4N",
                    "train_id": "470",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Warminster",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 10:43:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 10:43:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "N",
                    "path": "R4N",
                    "train_id": "9472",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Temple U",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 11:13:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 11:13:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "N",
                    "path": "R4N",
                    "train_id": "474",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Warminster",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 11:43:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 11:43:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "N",
                    "path": "R4N",
                    "train_id": "476",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Glenside",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 7 2014 12:13:00:000AM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 7 2014 12:13:00:000AM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Southbound": [
                {
                    "direction": "S",
                    "path": "R4S",
                    "train_id": "463",
                    "origin": "Warm",
                    "destination": "Airport",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": "30th Street Station",
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 08:49:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 08:49:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "S",
                    "path": "R4S",
                    "train_id": "465",
                    "origin": "Warm",
                    "destination": "Airport",
                    "status": "1 min",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": "Glenside",
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 09:19:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 09:19:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "S",
                    "path": "R4S",
                    "train_id": "9467",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Airport",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 09:49:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 09:49:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "S",
                    "path": "R4S",
                    "train_id": "469",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Airport",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 10:19:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 10:19:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "S",
                    "path": "R4S",
                    "train_id": "9471",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Airport",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 10:49:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 10:49:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "S",
                    "path": "R4S",
                    "train_id": "473",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Airport",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 11:19:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 11:19:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                },
                {
                    "direction": "S",
                    "path": "R4S",
                    "train_id": "9475",
                    "origin": null,
                    "destination": "Airport",
                    "status": "On Time",
                    "service_type": "LOCAL",
                    "next_station": null,
                    "sched_time": "Oct 6 2014 11:49:00:000PM",
                    "depart_time": "Oct 6 2014 11:49:00:000PM",
                    "track": "2",
                    "track_change": null,
                    "platform": " ",
                    "platform_change": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If it's easier to view, you may view the JSON at http://www3.septa.org/hackathon/Arrivals/90404/10/.
It appears the root node is dynamic and timestamped.  I want to access the information within both the "Northbound" and "Southbound" nodes.  However, every example I have been able to locate uses the root node and accesses child nodes through it.  Since the root node in this case is generated automatically and timestamped, I am not sure how to access the children.

I know that the following will correctly return 'N':

```
data['Airport Terminal A Departures: October 6, 2014, 8:31 pm'][0].Northbound[0].direction;
```

I am certain I am missing something obvious.  Assistance is most appreciated.

Comment: Try at least to format it using multiple lines, so it's easier to read...

Comment: Sorry about that.  Done.

Comment: What is the `root` of the `root` node?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get property value in js object when key is unknown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380930/how-to-get-property-value-in-js-object-when-key-is-unknown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var arr = obj[Object.keys(obj)];

var northbound = arr[0].Northbound;
var southbound = arr[1].Southbound;
```

Also, you may use a `for...in` loop:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
for(var i in obj) {
    if(obj[i].length) var arr = obj[i];
}
```

Now `arr` is an `array`, so you may `loop` or do something like this:

```
var northbound = arr[0].Northbound;
var southbound = arr[1].Southbound;
```

This is an abstract idea only. Hope you are able to do the rest :-)

Comment: I most certainly did!  Very straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you can access the object's keys by using:

```
var json = ...; /* your json here */
for (var key in json) {
    // Here the key variable will contain the key actual string, so...
    var secondLevel = json[key]; // Here you're accessing the second-level object (an array [])

    // Assuming the array only contains one Northbound and one Southbound parents...
    var northbound_parent = secondLevel[0];
    var southbound_parent = secondLevel[1];

    // And now get the actual Northbound and Southbound arrays
    var northbound = northbound_parent["Northbound"];
    var southbound = southbound_parent["Southbound"];

    // Here you have an array of objects...
    for (var i = 0; i < northbound.length; i++) // Repeat for southbound
    {
        var nb_values = northbound[i]; // Object with properties
        // Here you access them like nb_values["direction"]; and stuff
    }
}
```

Note that this code could be dramatically improved, but it is for you to understand it.

**Short answer:**
To access values with keys you don't know, you can check all keys inside that particular object:

```
for (var key in object)
{
    // key variable will contain the actual key (string, integer or whatever is being used), and each iteration will have one of the keys inside that object
}
```